# Help with ubuntu 11 mis-displays

Tags: 11.10, themes, display, interface

So, I sea [This](http://debianhelp.wordpress.com/2011/09/12/to-do-list-after-installing-ubuntu-11-10-aka-oneiric-ocelot/) tutorial, and I exectued this line in my terminal : `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lubuntu-desktop/ppa` & `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`
and my left-side panel changed abit, while the Dash Home changed to become like so : http://i43.tinypic.com/2vuc0lj.png ! help !

How can I change to the ubuntu default style or ppa ! because whene I run this : `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ppa` it gives me the follwing notice :

`gpg: requesting key A1231595 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key A1231595: "Launchpad PPA for Ubuntu Desktop" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1`

does this mean that the ubuntu ppa isn't changed or what ??

Please, help any help would very appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Install `ppa-purge` in your system

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

Use `ppa-purge` to remove the PPA you installed

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:lubuntu-desktop/ppa
```

Make sure that `lunbuntu-desktop` is not installed any more and try to remove further dependencies that the package installed

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge lubuntu-desktop
```

Re-install `ubuntu-desktop` let the system install any missing packages

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

What the first command does is install `ppa-puge`, its a small tool that removed PPAs from your system and attempts to install the previous version packages.

We are going to use it to remove ***ppa:lubuntu-desktop/ppa*** and any packages that you installed from that PPA with the second command.

The third command will remove the package `lubuntu-desktop` and any dependencies it installed in case `ppa-purge` missed any of those.

With the fourth command we will install `ubuntu-desktop` and any missing packages.

After this is all done you should log off and back on and hope that your desktop has been restored to normal.

Comment: That actually didn't do it ! Any more thoughts ??!